# IBOutlet Not Connecting to Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been dabbling with XCode. I'm very new to it but I have been doing some tutorials. I'm running XCode version Version 4.6 (4H127).

I have been following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGPJeYxWr3Y and at 4:36 is the bit I'm stuck at because my IBOutlet doesn't show in the popup - is there any reason why it wouldn't?

Here is my code:

ViewController.h: http://pastebin.com/ruJaXnKv
ViewController.m: http://pastebin.com/rhKKastC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was not connected to the right class. I thought it may of done this as default.